# get string[] using map on observable

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object which has id as an observable parameter. I want to make string[] using map().

When I am doing:

```
ids = students.map(student => student.id())
```

I am getting list of observables.
I am unable to understand why student.id() is not returning the list of string value?

Comment: Which library are you using and how is the value of `students` populated? It might help to add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect? You mapping an array of objects with an Oberservable to an array of Oberservables.
You have to subscribe somewhere for exmaple:

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
forkJoin(ids).subscribe(plainIds => myNewArr.push(...plainIds))
```